# connect azure functions to local signalr instance

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-functions, signalr, e2e-testing

I am currently writing tests for an existing project based on azure functions. The project uses signalr to send live update messages to the clients.

For my tests I am currently using a signalr instance, that is running in the cloud, but I need to replace it by a "local" instance on the system, that is running the tests, so i can be 100% sure, that the signalr message is coming from my test session.

Does anybody have an idea, how to get a signalr-server running in a docker container for my tests (i need a connection string i can provide for the azure functions app)?

I could not find anything online. I am sure I am not the only one, who wants to test if signalr messages are send correctly and i would prefer not to implement the signalr-server myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any way how to achieve this, so i created a repo with a small mock service for the SignalR service. I hope I am allowed to post such stuff here.

My [repo](https://github.com/woozar/signalr-mock) and my [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/woozar/signalr-mock)

Feel free to use / fork it. I am not sure if I will ever find any time to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

The bindings available in Azure Functions are for the Azure SignalR Service not SignalR itself, so there is no way unfortunately to test this locally.

You could simply instead just create a test Azure SignalR Service instance and use that instead.

Comment: That is far from being simple, because our test-runners do not have such kind of permissions and also with the amount of tests we execute all the time, it could get quite expensive to create such services all the time.